# data.table complex manipulation with rows elimination

Tags: r, data.table

Data sample is below: I have 3million rows.

```
Date,id,type,qty
9/30/14,1,’A’,10
9/30/14,2,’Z’,12
9/30/14,3,’B’,15
9/30/14,1,’B’,20
9/30/14,1,’Z’,20
9/30/14,1,’A’,20
9/30/14,2,’B’,20
9/30/14,3,’B’,5
9/30/14,3,’A’,40
```

I want result as below:

```
Date,id,type,Qty
9/30/14,1,A,20
9/30/14,1,B,20
9/30/14,2,B,20
9/30/14,3,B,5
9/30/14,3,’A’,40
```

Logic is below:  On the same date, pick the latest qty (from the later record) for each id and type.Ignore types y and Z.

Comment: Are we just supposed to guess what technologies you are using here? What have you tried?

Comment: The `data.table` tag is associated with R, but this is just csv data with homework instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DT[,.(Qty=last(qty)),by=.(Date,id,type)][type!='Z'][order(id)]
```

Comment: Perfect - this definitely helps in what I want to do.